# Flip UIView pre-iOS 4 from left to right

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, ios, flip

I know there's a simple `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft` and way to implement that, but how do you do something similar (i.e. flip a `UIView` over) pre-iOS 4, like on the `iPad`, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[UIView beginAnimations: @"flipOverCard1" context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5f];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView: card1 cache: YES];

// Stuff to do while transitioning

[UIView commitAnimations];
```